# factoring LALR grammar

Tags: grammar, lalr, ply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python/YACC: Resolving a shift/reduce conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939888/python-yacc-resolving-a-shift-reduce-conflict)

I am trying to create a parser using Ply, which implements a LALR(1) parser like Yacc. However, I've run into a difficult reduce/reduce conflict. As far as I can tell, there is no ambiguity in my grammar, instead, the conflict stems from the limited lookahead of a LALR(1) parser. I'm guessing that the problem occurs when `A A` is encountered because the parser needs to know if there is a third token to decide whether to reduce to `t1` or not. So how can I factor this into a grammar which requires only single token lookahead?

```
from ply import lex, yacc

tokens = ('A','B')
t_A = 'A'
t_B = 'B'

def p_top(p):
    'top : t1\n| t2'

def p_1(p):
    't1 : t7 t6'

def p_2(p):
    't2 : t3 t4\n| B'

def p_3(p):
    't3 : t6\n| B'

def p_4(p):
    't4 : t5 t5\n| B'

def p_5(p):
    't5 : t6\n| B'

def p_6(p):
    't6 : A'

def p_7(p):
    't7 : A'

lexer = lex.lex()
parser = yacc.yacc(debug=True)
parser.parse('AAA')
```

Here is the relevant state in Ply's debugging output, though I can't make much sense of it.

```
state 1

    (13) t7 -> A .
    (12) t6 -> A .

  ! reduce/reduce conflict for A resolved using rule 12 (t6 -> A .)
    B               reduce using rule 12 (t6 -> A .)
    A               reduce using rule 12 (t6 -> A .)

  ! A               [ reduce using rule 13 (t7 -> A .) ]
```

Comment: Looks like either `t3` or `t5` can be `t6\n| B`, and either `t6` or `t7` can be `A`.  Is that allowed?  Is it useful?

Comment: Yes it's allowed and yes it is useful. This is actually part of a much larger grammar for an assembler I wrote, but I just took a minimal example to make things easier to understand.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2939888/1240268)? Also, I needed to add  `start='top'` to my `yacc.yacc` call to give this error...

Comment: That's odd. By default it chooses the first rule as the start. Did you accidentally put another rule before top?

Comment: *It seemed to also be the case on my home computer (copying and pasting your code)...* I like how [the docs](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn27) describe tracking down reduce/reduce as "one of the finer pleasures of using an LR parsing algorithm" requiring "appropriately high level of caffeination"...

Comment: I think this *is* a different question (i.e. not a duplicate) for one thing it is about `reduce/reduce` rather than `shift/reduce`... it seems that there should be some standard tricks/resources for resolving both `shift/reduce` and `reduce/reduce` errors...